Microsoft Graph API not returning all Calendar Events
I am using the MS Graph API to extract all meetings data from a specific MS tenant. The data I am recieving does not match outlook calendar's within the tenant when I try to validate. Is this a common issue with the MS Graph API? I have triple-checked that my extraction is full proof. Any ideas?
I have verified my extraction process, and the only thing that I can think of is that the Graph API does not fully track all Outlook Calendar events. Has anyone worked with this API and run into any of these issues before?

You need to include the code you use, one common reason you would see that is that you failed to expand recurring appointments using a calendarview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
